# why do I have a 'debug.keystore.lock' file in my .android directory

Tags: android, android-keystore

couldn't find a single hit on this on SO or the web.

I'm having a lot of issues with 'Default activity not found', so I have to reimport from github or do the 'Invalidate Cache/Restart/Sync Gradle' dance, which is really testing my patience, so I wonder if that's related.

I also noticed that my `default.keystore` file itself was overwritten, so I had to copy my original over.

And after deleting the lock file, it just reappeared ...

anyway, trying to understand the meaning of `debug.keystore.lock` instead of just guessing, maybe someone knows the facts.